# Posso adicionar funções dentro do método render?

Tags: javascript, react

É uma má prática chamar funções e/ou adicionar estruturas (condicionais, interação) dentro do método render do componente antes do return, por exemplo:

```
export default class Header extends Component {

    funcao() {
        ...
    }

    render() {
        this.funcao();
        return (
            ...
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: O que essa função faz? Acho que não tem problema...

Comment: Do jeito que você exemplificou não tem validade, não é correto e porque somente na hora de renderizar? você precisa criar um exemplo minimo mais real, o que a função vai fazer? talvez existem métodos melhores para resolver isso e momentos melhores. Enfim diga o que vai fazer, se for de maneira genérica a sua pergunta pode até ser fechada, então sempre foque no problema

Answer (score 0):

Sugiro que faça do seguinte jeito já que está em classes:

```js
export default class Header extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {

    }

    render() {
            return (
                    ...
            )
    }
}
```

Assim ele executará uma função assim que o seu componente for renderizado que eu acho que era o seu objetivo.